# why doesn't this custom binding work?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, tags, tag-it

I´m trying to use tag-it with knockout:

This is my html:

```
<input placeholder="Tags" class="tagsInput" data-bind="tags:{}, tagitOptions: { initiateTags: myTags, tagSource: allMyTags, placeholder: 't-æ-g-g'}" />
```

where

```
myTags = ko.observableArray([]);
allMytags = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and my binding is like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tags = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().tagitOptions || {};

        $(element).tagit(options);

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        //I´ll leave this til later...
    }
```

}

Firebug is telling me that options.initiateTags() = [ "myTag1", "myTag2" ]
and options.placeholder = "t-æ-g-g".
but tagit doesn´t show my initiateTags. Why?

Comment: There is no mention in official docs (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) that using `.tagit` plugin with `<input/>` is supported, but with `<ul>` lists only.

Comment: Hmm. You might be right. However https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#singlefieldnode-domnode seems to indicate otherwise, or do I misinterpret it?

Comment: @AsleG it should work with an `input` element see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using observable properties in your `tagitOptions` then you need to unwrap them before passing them to `tagit`.

The easiest option is to use the `ko.toJS` function which recursively turns observable properties to regular properties.

So modify your `init` function to:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().tagitOptions || {};

    $(element).tagit(ko.toJS(options));
},
```

But to make it actually work:

The tagIt plugin is not playing nicely with Knockout so to make it work you need to use the `value` binding before your `tag` where you can specify the current value of your input:

```
<input placeholder="Tags" class="tagsInput" 
   data-bind="value: myTags, tags:{}, 
           tagitOptions: { availableTags: myTags, placeholderText: 't-æ-g-g'}" />
```

And in your binding handler you need to use the `setTimeout` trick:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().tagitOptions || {};

    setTimeout(function (){$(element).tagit(ko.toJS(options))},1);

},
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/MH6f4/).

Comment: Thanx a lot, nemesv! :)
Now that I know how that works I have to figure out why the "availableTags" isn´t put as tags in my input-field which is part of an accordion, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MH6f4/1/

Comment: @AsleG so far you haven't talked about any accordion, so this is now a different question... but if want some help you need to make your jsFiddle work at least the accordion part, or you need to post your `jqAccordion` binding... because without the `jqAccordion` binding it works: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/MH6f4/2/

Comment: I know I haven´t mention the accordion. I try to isolate the problem as the complexity soon gets out of hand, as you might see in this attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/MH6f4/4/ ;)
Even if the fiddle doesn´t work, the jqAccordion works in my computer (the tagit-input does not). If I haven´t confused you too much, maybe you are able to see what is wrong?

Comment: I've fixed the all the errors in your fiddle what I've seen the console. The tag editor is working fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/vpGd9/

Comment: Thanx, nemesv. :) I think I introduced those errors when making the fiddle. Thing is I still can´t get it to work on my computer.
Two issues: The setTimeout() in tags-handler for some (very) strange reason interrupt the fiddler-equivalent for-loop where I populate my TaskTags-array. (Effect on my computer: Outside the accordion I have a "div" with a data-bind="with SelectedTask" span-ing the "TaskTag"-array and only the first tag is shown there.)
this behaviour return to normal if I comment out the setTimeout-function leaving only the line "$(element).tagit(ko.toJS(options))".

Comment: The other thing is that I still can´t see the tags on my computer.
Without the setTimeout-function the tagSource-option works, but even when removing the tagSource option from tagitOptions, the "availableTags" is not shown as tags. (I have tested with the same data-array for both tagSource and availableTags, to be sure it has nothing to do with the underlying data.)

Comment: Now I have the exact same code regarding HTMl and handlers in fiddler as on my computer. I have tested with the same array as "tagSource" and as "availableTags".  In fiddler it works, on my computer, the tags wouldn´t show. I really don´t understand that there could be any differences. Could this due to DotnetNuke (I´m running my code on a localhost DNN-site)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DotnetNuke so I don't know how could effect this. Some ideas for the debugging: you need to make sure that you are using the exact same jquery, ko, tagit, etc. version and they are loaded correctly. Also in the fiddle all your code runs on the page load event, so make sure that you also run your code on page load.

Comment: I copied the code from http://jsfiddle.net/vpGd9 back in my DNN-module project and the tags will not show, so I reckon DNN is at fault somehow...?

Comment: Any differences I can find is that DNN is using jquery-ui 1.10.3.
If I uncheck jquery-ui option in "framework and extension" and add "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" as "external resources" the fiddler accordion stops working all together